# Module List not updating after removing extension

Tags: magento2.4.3.p1

I had MageWorx Order-Editor installed directly to the `app/code`. I then removed it so I could install the updated version through composer. After I installed the composer version of the module, I was getting some problems so I then disabled and removed the module with the composer.

Currently, I'm getting this error on the front end of my store:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): The contents from the "/var/www/html/vendor/mageworx/module-ordersbase/etc/module.xml" file can't be read. Warning!file_get_contents(/var/www/html/vendor/mageworx/module-ordersbase/etc/module.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): The contents from the "/var/www/html/vendor/mageworx/module-ordersbase/etc/module.xml" file can't be read. Warning!file_get_contents(/var/www/html/vendor/mageworx/module-ordersbase/etc/module.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList\Loader->getModuleConfigs() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/ModuleList/Loader.php:83]
#2 Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList\Loader->load() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/ModuleList.php:72]
#3 Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList->getAll() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/ModuleList.php:91]
#4 Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList->getOne() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php:144]
#5 Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isModuleVersionEqual() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php:59]
#6 Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isSchemaUpToDate() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php:103]
#7 Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->getDbVersionErrors() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php:119]
#8 Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->getGroupedDbVersionErrors() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php:53]
#9 Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->beforeDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:121]
#10 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/amasty/aminvisiblecaptcha/Plugin/Framework/App/FrontControllerInterface/ValidateCaptcha.php:118]
#11 Amasty\InvisibleCaptcha\Plugin\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface\ValidateCaptcha->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#12 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:75]
#13 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#15 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:29]
</pre>
```

I have triple-checked that there are no MageWorx files in either vendor or `app/code`. There are no references to MageWork modules in `composer.json/lock` or `app/etc/config.php`.
I have also removed all references in my database to anything MageWorx related and dropped their associated tables.

grep shows that mageworx is the only reference in log files.

I don't understand why Magento is still looking for this extension ????

Things I've tried already:
Flushed & Cleared Cache,
Deleting generated files,
bin/magento setup:upgrade,
bin/magento setup:di:compile,
deleting vendor/* and running composer install

What am I missing?

Comment: check if that module is still present in setup_module table?

Comment: hey @magetnouser, I forgot to mention that I deleted the entries from setup_module as well.

Comment: did you solve this issue?